# How to add video uploader to the WordPress Customizer?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm struggling to add a video uploader for my WordPress theme, can anyone help?

I have this in the functions.php file:

```
function andys_theme_customizer( $wp_customize ) {

        // Andys Video Section

    $wp_customize->add_section("Videosection", array(
        "title" => __("Video Section", "customizer_ads_sections"),
        "priority" => 20,
    ));

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'video_upload',
   array(
      'default' => '',
      'transport' => 'refresh',
      'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
             'type' => 'theme_mod',
   )
);

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Media_Control( $wp_customize, 'video_upload',
   array(
      'label' => __( 'Default Media Control' ),
      'description' => esc_html__( 'This is the description for the Media Control' ),
      'section' => 'Videosection',
      'mime_type' => 'video',  // Required. Can be image, audio, video, application, text
      'button_labels' => array( // Optional
         'select' => __( 'Select File' ),
         'change' => __( 'Change File' ),
         'default' => __( 'Default' ),
         'remove' => __( 'Remove' ),
         'placeholder' => __( 'No file selected' ),
         'frame_title' => __( 'Select File' ),
         'frame_button' => __( 'Choose File' ),

      )
   )
) );



}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'andys_theme_customizer' );
```

And this on my page template:

```
<div class="video-container">
         <button style="position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;" onclick="playPause(); return false;">Click to start</button>
    
             <video loop controls poster="http://test.guerrilla.nz/wp-content/themes/advocate/images/David_Buckingham.jpg">
<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'video_upload' ) ?>
        <source src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'video_upload' ) ?>" width="100" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'video_upload' ) ?>" type="video/ogg">
          <source src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'video_upload' ) ?>" type="video/ogg">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
        </div>
```

However the video is not uploading, can anyone assist?

Comment: Is this the full code block from functions.php? I'm not seeing the function definition and then the add_action part.

Comment: Hi Arslan:


here is the add action:    


add_action( 'customize_register', 'andys_theme_customizer' );                


And as for the function definition, the above code is inside:    


function andys_theme_customizer( $wp_customize ) {  }

Comment: I moved the code snippet from OP answer into OP question.

Answer (score 1):

There was only an integer inserted for the src="" of my video.
The solution was to put the "wp_get_attachment_url()" around "get_theme_mod()".

So it must be: `<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_theme_mod('video_upload')) ?>` as source. Then the correct url will be inserted instead of its ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code in the template to this:

```
<div class="video-container">
<?php
$id = get_theme_mod('video_upload');

$attr = array(
    'src' => wp_get_attachment_url($id)
);

echo wp_video_shortcode( $attr );
?>
</div>
```

Have a look at the documentation [wp_video_shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_video_shortcode).

Comment: Thanks Arslan, this works great, however my css classes no longer work now how do I size this video responcively and add a poster image or even other attributes?

Comment: .video-container {
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    padding-top:30px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed, .video-container video {
    position:absolute;
      display: block;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100% !important;
     min-width: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     z-index: 1000;
     overflow: hidden;
    padding: 100px 100px 100px 100px ;

}

Comment: You need to look at the documentation of wp_video_shortcode for settings like poster, autoplay, width, height etc

Comment: Hi Arslan, can not figure out how to output it, I need something like this:

Comment: <div class="video-container">
<?php
$id = get_theme_mod('video_upload');

$attr = array(
    'src' => wp_get_attachment_url($id),
 'width'    => 100%,
);

echo wp_video_shortcode( $attr );
?>
</div>